# Powershell — concatenation generates Unicode error in JSON parser

Tags: json, mongodb, powershell, unicode

I downloaded a set of 64,354 JSON-formatted Supreme Court opinions from courtlistener.com and am attempting to load them into a MongoDB collection. Each of these original files is a JSON object enclosed in curly brackets, which generates an error in MongoDB Compass:

> Import completed with following errors:     0 / 23
>
> Operation passed in cannot be an Array

I can successfully import them by enclosing that original curly-bracketed object in square brackets using a text editor. But when I attempt to automate that process for all 64,354 files, I get the following error on import of any one of them:

> Failed to import with the following error:     0 / ~0
>
> Unexpected token "�" (0xFFFD) in JSON at position 0 while parsing "�"
> in C:\Users\franc\Desktop\bathwater\20220115-courtlistener-opinions
> (unicode error maybe\1728.json
>
> 1 | � | ^

When I open the new file in a hex editor I see that it now starts with a U+FFFE which is not present in the original. If there is a way to tell PowerShell to not do that, I believe that will solve my problem.

Here is the PowerShell approach I used:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\franc\Desktop\bathwater\20220115-courtlistener-opinions\" -Filter "*.json" | foreach {"["+"`r`n" + (get-content $_.FullName -raw) + "`n"+"]" | Out-File $_.FullName; Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination "C:\Users\franc\Desktop\bathwater\20220115-courtlistener-opinions\out\"}
```

Comment: What PowerShell version are you using? You can try specifying the encoding for the output.

Comment: I am using version 5.1.22533.1001. Will take a look at output encodings. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Try writing files [_without BOM_](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpowershell%5Dwrite+file+no+bom).

Comment: In Windows PowerShell (which you're running), `Out-File` creates "Unicode" (UTF-16LE) files by default, which invariably have a BOM (the character `U+FFFE` (two bytes) at the very start of the file). While you can use `-Encoding utf8` to create UTF-8 files instead, note that they invariably have a (UTF-8) BOM too. (By contrast, PowerShell (Core) 7+ now consistently defaults to BOM-_less_ UTF-8). To create BOM-less UTF-8 files,  you need to use .NET APIs directly - see the link in JosefZ's comment. If your data happens to contain ASCII characters only, you can get away with `-Encoding Ascii`